Determining most appropriate imputation method for MAR multivariate data with large NA % and corresponding implementation strategy
I have a large dataset (~6700 rows and 41 columns) containing data per country per year on various indicators (originating from the Worldwide Governance Indicators, for those curious). By nature, this dataset is very gappy: not all countries are scored every year on every indicator. I intend on creating my own composite indices in R based on a subset of the indicators using PCA. However, PCA does not allow for NA values (to my knowledge), which required me to either delete missing values entirely or try to somehow impute them. My preference goes out to the latter where possible.
Excel screenshot of my dataset
structure(list(Alpha.3.Code = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), levels = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO", "ALB", "ARE", "ARG", "ARM", 
"ASM", "ATG", "AUS", "AUT", "AZE", "BDI", "BEL", "BEN", "BFA", 
"BGD", "BGR", "BHR", "BHS", "BIH", "BLR", "BLZ", "BOL", "BRA", 
"BRB", "BRN", "BTN", "BWA", "CAF", "CAN", "CHE", "CHL", "CHN", 
"CIV", "CMR", "COG", "COK", "COL", "COM", "CPV", "CRI", "CUB", 
"CYM", "CYP", "CZE", "DEU", "DJI", "DMA", "DNK", "DOM", "DZA", 
"ECU", "EGY", "ERI", "ESP", "EST", "ETH", "FIN", "FJI", "FRA", 
"FSM", "GAB", "GBR", "GEO", "GHA", "GIN", "GMB", "GNB", "GNQ", 
"GRC", "GRD", "GRL", "GTM", "GUF", "GUM", "GUY", "HKG", "HND", 
"HRV", "HTI", "HUN", "IDN", "IND", "IRL", "IRN", "IRQ", "ISL", 
"ISR", "ITA", "JAM", "JEY", "JOR", "JPN", "KAZ", "KEN", "KGZ", 
"KHM", "KIR", "KNA", "KOR", "KWT", "LAO", "LBN", "LBR", "LBY", 
"LCA", "LIE", "LKA", "LSO", "LTU", "LUX", "LVA", "MAC", "MAR", 
"MCO", "MDA", "MDG", "MDV", "MEX", "MHL", "MKD", "MLI", "MLT", 
"MMR", "MNE", "MNG", "MOZ", "MRT", "MUS", "MWI", "MYS", "NAM", 
"NER", "NGA", "NIC", "NIU", "NLD", "NOR", "NPL", "NRU", "NZL", 
"OMN", "PAK", "PAN", "PER", "PHL", "PLW", "PNG", "POL", "PRI", 
"PRK", "PRT", "PRY", "QAT", "RUS", "RWA", "SAU", "SDN", "SEN", 
"SGP", "SLB", "SLE", "SLV", "SMR", "SOM", "SRB", "SSD", "STP", 
"SUR", "SVK", "SVN", "SWE", "SWZ", "SYC", "SYR", "TCD", "TGO", 
"THA", "TJK", "TKM", "TON", "TTO", "TUN", "TUR", "TUV", "TWN", 
"TZA", "UGA", "UKR", "URY", "USA", "UZB", "VCT", "VEN", "VNM", 
"VUT", "WSM", "YEM", "ZAF", "ZMB", "ZWE"), class = "factor"), 
    Country.Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = c("Afghanistan", 
    "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
    "Argentina", "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", 
    "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", 
    "Belarus", "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bhutan", "Bolivia (Plurinational State of)", 
    "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil", "Brunei Darussalam", 
    "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cabo Verde", "Cambodia", 
    "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", 
    "Chad", "Chile", "China", "Colombia", "Comoros", "Congo", 
    "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica", "Côte d'Ivoire", "Croatia", 
    "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czechia", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", 
    "Dominican Republic", "Ecuador", "Egypt", "El Salvador", 
    "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Eswatini", "Ethiopia", 
    "Fiji", "Finland", "France", "French Guiana", "Gabon", "Gambia", 
    "Georgia", "Germany", "Ghana", "Greece", "Greenland", "Grenada", 
    "Guam", "Guatemala", "Guinea", "Guinea-Bissau", "Guyana", 
    "Haiti", "Honduras", "Hong Kong", "Hungary", "Iceland", "India", 
    "Indonesia", "Iran (Islamic Republic of)", "Iraq", "Ireland", 
    "Israel", "Italy", "Jamaica", "Japan", "Jersey", "Jordan", 
    "Kazakhstan", "Kenya", "Kiribati", "Korea (Democratic People's Republic of)", 
    "Korea, Republic of", "Kuwait", "Kyrgyzstan", "Lao People's Democratic Republic", 
    "Latvia", "Lebanon", "Lesotho", "Liberia", "Libya", "Liechtenstein", 
    "Lithuania", "Luxembourg", "Macao", "Madagascar", "Malawi", 
    "Malaysia", "Maldives", "Mali", "Malta", "Marshall Islands", 
    "Mauritania", "Mauritius", "Mexico", "Micronesia (Federated States of)", 
    "Moldova, Republic of", "Monaco", "Mongolia", "Montenegro", 
    "Morocco", "Mozambique", "Myanmar", "Namibia", "Nauru", "Nepal", 
    "Netherlands", "New Zealand", "Nicaragua", "Niger", "Nigeria", 
    "Niue", "North Macedonia", "Norway", "Oman", "Pakistan", 
    "Palau", "Panama", "Papua New Guinea", "Paraguay", "Peru", 
    "Philippines", "Poland", "Portugal", "Puerto Rico", "Qatar", 
    "Russian Federation", "Rwanda", "Saint Kitts and Nevis", 
    "Saint Lucia", "Saint Vincent and the Grenadines", "Samoa", 
    "San Marino", "Sao Tome and Principe", "Saudi Arabia", "Senegal", 
    "Serbia", "Seychelles", "Sierra Leone", "Singapore", "Slovakia", 
    "Slovenia", "Solomon Islands", "Somalia", "South Africa", 
    "South Sudan", "Spain", "Sri Lanka", "Sudan", "Suriname", 
    "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syrian Arab Republic", "Taiwan, Province of China", 
    "Tajikistan", "Tanzania, United Republic of", "Thailand", 
    "Togo", "Tonga", "Trinidad and Tobago", "Tunisia", "Turkey", 
    "Turkmenistan", "Tuvalu", "Uganda", "Ukraine", "United Arab Emirates", 
    "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland", "United States of America", 
    "Uruguay", "Uzbekistan", "Vanuatu", "Venezuela (Bolivarian Republic of)", 
    "Viet Nam", "Yemen", "Zambia", "Zimbabwe"), class = "factor"), 
    Year = structure(1:6, levels = c("1996", "1997", "1998", 
    "1999", "2000", "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", 
    "2007", "2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2014", 
    "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2020", "2021", "2022"
    ), class = "factor"), ADB.1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), AFR.1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), AFR.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), ASD.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), BTI.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), BTI.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), BTI.3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), BTI.4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), EIU.3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), FRH.1 = c(0, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, NA), GCB.1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GII.1 = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GII.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GII.3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), GWP.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HRM.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HRM.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), HUM.1 = c(0.5, 
    NA, 0, NA, 0, NA), HUM.2 = c(0, NA, 0, NA, 0, NA), IPD.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), IPD.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), IPD.3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), IPD.4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), LBO.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), LBO.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), LBO.3 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), LBO.4 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), LBO.5 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), MSI.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), PRS.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), VAB.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), VDEM.1 = c(0.0511238899760904, 
    NA, 0.0462430233193522, NA, 0.0462430233193522, NA), VDEM.2 = c(0.295083812572078, 
    NA, 0.347879972795187, NA, 0.347879972795187, NA), VDEM.3 = c(0.0556322642520707, 
    NA, 0.0415629039432011, NA, 0.0415629039432011, NA), WCY.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WCY.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WJP.1 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), WJP.2 = c(NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

After filtering out the smaller countries which were never included in any of the indicators, this is the % of missing values per indicator
p_missing <- unlist(lapply(full_data, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))/nrow(full_data)
sort(p_missing[p_missing > 0], decreasing = TRUE)

Percentage of missing values per indicator
The strategy I had come up with is as follows

For countries which have more than two values included, use an imputation method (I'll get to this in a bit)
For countries which have only one value included, use mean imputation
For countries with no values included, run all other analyses first and then fill them with the mean of all values in the entire dataset. These are not used in the final analysis and data representation but allow me to run the PCA

The issue I am facing is in the selection of the imputation method in step 1. Considering the amount of NA values in my data, I planned on using Multiple Imputations by Chained Equations (MICE, or simply Multiple Imputations). However, my data are also quite collinear, which MICE has difficulty with. I was wondering whether there are other imputation methods out there which are better suited for my purpose, or whether there are transformations (ideally other than deletion) which would increase the odds of MICE working out for me.
In addition, I was wondering whether it makes more sense to run the MICE on the entire dataset at once, or group the dataset by country and run the analysis per country?
I am very inexperienced when it comes to statistics, but I have spent a long time trying to understand the language and technical details of imputation in general as well as MICE specifically. I have delved into the specifications of MICE, as well as Random Forest, missForest and Expectation Maximization, have watched online tutorials, and have asked for help from professors at my uni (which don't have the time to help me due to the holidays). Finally, I have used trial and error in combination with ChatGPT to try and understand the syntax and errors I am receiving.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61721060/apply-pca-to-data-with-na-values-in-r ?

I saw that thread as well, and tried to get NIPALS to work. However, even after removing as many empty rows as I can justify, NIPALS still gives an error because of a few rows being entirely empty. Thus, I would need imputation to solve this, which is how I ended up at MICE.

Not thinking about it too carefully, but is there anything wrong with just dropping the entirely-empty rows from the data set?

Additionally, you'll want to reconsider your approach. Currently, it's an ad-hoc approach with no real justification, although your intuition is ok. Essentially you'll want a model for missing data that draws on information from other countries when one country has little information to offer for guessing the missing values. Here's an overview of different methods you might use: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3016756/

@socialscientist thanks for the welcome and the tip! I looked at your source and am thoroughly intimidated. Do you perhaps have a source which is easier for beginners to understand? If not, I'll try and work my way through the paper

For the "quick and dirty" I'd suggest using MICE in this way https://www.gerkovink.com/miceVignettes/Multi_level/Multi_level_data.html

Thanks for pointing that link out, I hadn't found that one yet. I am very close to what I'm trying to achieve. However, I receive errors due to collinearity and no predictors being left. Is it best to leave those out or is better to somehow increase the tolerance?
